# django app config values storage

Tags: django, architecture

How should I store parameters for application configuration?
For example. I've application for calculation of taxes in my project. There is few values I need to save once for long time without changes but with possibility to edit them(taxes, payment commissions, etc). Should I create some *config.py* file or create model *config*? Maybe there is other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to configurate parameters in some calculation, I would go with *model* object and initial *fixture*. Because it's stored in database, you can change it anytime.

For example:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

and fixture (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/initial-data/):

```
[
    {
        "model": "myapp.setting",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "key": "[SOME_PARAMETER_KEY]",
            "value": "[some value]",
            "description": "[some description]"
        }
    }
]
```